# How to align memory address of Windows x64 C++ global variable

Tags: c++, memory-address, memory-alignment

I want the address of the global variable I create to be a multiple of 0x1000.

sample

```
char alignstr[0x100] = "this is align string";
int main()
{
    printf("var address = [%p]", &alignstr);
}

output

"var address = [0x140005000]"
```

Comment: What is the platform/os/cpu?

Comment: visual studio c++ / windows 7 ~ 11 x64 / intel or amd

Comment: Why would you even want a global variable?

Comment: Because I want my variables to be stored in the .data section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas):

```
alignas(0x1000) char alignstr[0x100] = "this is align string";
```